# Resume processing of a Java Stream after running findFirst()

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type, findfirst

Given a simple list of strings:

```java
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Mary", "James", "Jim", "Camilla");
```

I'd like to process each item of the list with a `anotherMethod()` method, however the first item shall be processed additionally by `someMethod()`.

I've tried something like this:

```java
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Mary", "James", "Jim", "Camilla");

var result = strings.stream()
     .findFirst()
     .map(myString -> someMethod(myString))
     // "resume" stream
     .map(myString -> anotherMethod(myString))
     .toList();
```

Is there a way to handle such a scenario using a `Stream` or something similar?

---

#### Update 1

Here is an example to help you better understand the motivation behind my question.

```java
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Mary", "James", "Jim", "Camilla");

public String someMethod(String s) {
  return s.toUpperCase();
}

public String anotherMethod(String s) {
  return s.toLowerCase();
}
```

The final result shall be a `List<String>` with the following elements, that is, only the first element is converted to upper-case while all other elements are converted to lower-case.

`"MARY", "james", "jim", "camilla"`

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by using `findFirst`?

Comment: The reason I mentioned `findFirst` is I need to process only the first item of the list with an additional method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findFirst` collapses the stream to an `Optional<String>`, and there is nothing to resume.

```
Optional<String> mary = Stream.of("Mary", "James", "Jim", "Camilla").findFirst();
```

Do you want to reduce the stream to only one element? Then the method `limit(1)` might be what you are looking for and then concat it with a copy where you `skip(1)` the element.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Mary", "James", "Jim", "Camilla");
List<String> result = Stream.concat(
      strings.stream()
        .limit(1)
        .map(this::someMethod),
      strings.stream()
        .skip(1))
        .map(this::anotherMethod)
     ).toList();
```

## Edit: After Update 1:

You wouldn't want to apply `toLowerCase()` to the first element after you applied `toUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an `IntStream` over the indexes.

```java
IntStream.range(0, strings.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> {
        var s = strings.get(i);
        if (i == 0) s = someMethod(s);
        return anotherMethod(s);
    }).toList();
```

Answer (score 2):

## [`Optional.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#stream())

Your idea of using `findFirst()` is perfectly viable.

We can apply `map()` on the `Optional` result and make use of the Java 9 `Optional.stream()` (to "resume" the stream).

`flatMap()` operation in conjunction with `Stream.concat()` would be handy for combining the very first element with the rest part of the stream.

Apply the final transformation and collect the result into a list.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Mary", "James", "Jim", "Camilla");

List<String> result = strings.stream().findFirst()
    .map(MyClass::someMethod)
    .stream()
    .flatMap(s -> Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(s), 
        strings.stream().skip(1).map(MyClass::anotherMethod)
    ))
    .toList();
```

## [`Iterator.forEachRemaining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html)

Another option would be to use Java 8 `Iterator.forEachRemaining()`:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Mary", "James", "Jim", "Camilla");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

Iterator<String> iterator = strings.iterator();
result.add(someMethod(iterator.next()));
iterator.forEachRemaining(s -> result.add(anotherMethod(s));
```

Comment: The OP wants to process all the elements from the original stream, and interpose *extra* processing for the first one of them.  Handling the second and subsequent elements of the original stream is whath they mean by "resuming" the stream.  The approach based on `Optional.stream()` doesn't do that at all.

Comment: The collector-based approach, on the other hand, has a subtler flaw: it does not satisfy the associativity constraint on collectors.  It will likely work in many cases, but it will not produce the same results when a computation is split.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The second solution handles everything using a single stream. And BTW, from this statement I infer that any approach will do *Is there a way to handle such a scenario using a Stream or something similar?*

Comment: The issue is not about ordering.  It is about there (possibly) being multiple partial results to combine.  Your accumulator will perform extra processing on the first item accumulated into *each* partial result, but that processing is wanted only for the first item overall in the stream.

Comment: This is a matter of correctness, not overhead.  Your collector will produce *different output* depending on how many ways the stream is split.  Which is where I started: it does not satisfy the associativity constraint on collectors.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Agree, updated the answer.

Comment: I like `Iterator.forEachRemaining()` for this.  It's not a stream, but I would account it "something similar", and it affords a clear, compact implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) or [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common) (I'm the developer of this library)

```
var result = StreamEx.of(strings)
           .mapFirstOrElse(String::toUpperCase, String::toLowerCase)
           .toList();

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 final AtomicBoolean processFirstElement = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        strings.stream()
                .map(input->processFirstElement.getAndSet(false)?
                                someMethod(input)
                                :input)
                .map(YourClass::anotherMethod)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Ideally we should avoid using mutable objects,AtomicBoolean should be able to maintain happens-before and hence prevent racing condition.